# Problem excluding category from get_next_post

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, navigation, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have a custom post type called "exhibitions" that uses the native "category" taxonomy. I have three categories: Current, Past, and Featured. Posts get marked either Current or Past and some are also marked as Featured.

I want my next/prev links on single pages to exclude the 'featured' category (tag_ID=21) so that my current and past posts don't cross over when users are using post navigation, but I can't seem to get this to happen. I have tried:

`get_next_post(true,'21')`, `get_next_post(false,'21')` and pretty much every other permutation of arguments, but my Past/Featured posts continue to show up adjacent to my Current/Featured posts in the post navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with: `get_adjacent_post` ?

```
get_adjacent_post(false, 'YourID', false);
```

wp topic: [get_adjacent_posts-exclude-category-syntax](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_adjacent_posts-exclude-category-syntax)

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer. An answer here should stand alone and not be dependent upon a third party link.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd parameter enables you to exclude category I.D's

```
 $excluded_categories
(string) (optional) Excluded categories IDs.

    Default: '' 

 <?php get_next_post( $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories ) ?>
```

Source https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

Same with get_adjacent_post()

```
 <?php get_adjacent_post( $in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous ) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Word.ress 3.9 (and still in 3.9.1) there's a **bug** concerning the excluded terms in `get_adjacent_post()`. There's a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fixed-adjacent-post/) to fix that bug.