# get_adjacent_post_link excluded_terms ignored

Tags: categories, taxonomy, navigation, terms

I call the function ´get_adjacent_post_link´ using the argument ´$excluded_terms´. But this argument is ignored.

This is how I call the function.

```
get_adjacent_post_link(
    '%link',
    '<span class="forward"></span>',
    false,
    array(83, 88, 89, 182),
    true
);
```

By clicking the resulting link I can reach a post that is in the category 'Blog Eintrag (de)' which has this admin URL

```
/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?action=edit&taxonomy=category&tag_ID=83&post_type=post
```

I think that a post with this category should be excluded by the argument ´array(83, 88, 89, 182)´. Why is it not?

My Wordpress version is 3.9.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has [the same solution as that one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136161/problem-excluding-category-from-get-next-post/156030#156030). The answer is short, so I post it here as well:

> In WordPress 3.9 (and still in 3.9.1) there's a bug concerning the
>   excluded terms in get_adjacent_post(). There's a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fixed-adjacent-post/) to fix
>   that bug.